# Delete a property (array) in the reduce and map?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am deleting `State` property (`delete entry.State;`) in the `Entries` array after doing the mapping in the `reduce` block. I feel this code is code-smell.

I no longer need the `State` property after done the mapping, what the right way to remove it?

You can see I am returning a list of State and Data object without State (which has been removed).

```js
const data = {
  FirstName: "Paul",
  LastName: "Allen",
  Email: "name@domain.com",
  Entries: [
    {
      EntryId: "FF-DD",
      Title: "Item 1",
      State: [
        { Name: "Lock 1", Time: "1563479611" },
        { Name: "Lock 2", Time: "1563479663" }
      ]
    },
    {
      EntryId: "GG-RR",
      Title: "Item 2",
      State: [
        { Name: "Run 1", Time: "116479611" },
        { Name: "Run 2", Time: "126347963" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const newData = createArray(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2));

function createArray(data) {
  let cloneData = { ...data };
  
  cloneData.EmailAddress = cloneData.Email;
  delete cloneData.Email;

  const states = cloneData.Entries.reduce((stateBlock, entry) => {
    const states = entry.State.map(state => {
      const CreatedTime = state.Time;
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        CreatedTime: CreatedTime,
        EntryId: entry.EntryId
      }

      delete newState.Time;
      return newState;
    });

    stateBlock.push(...states);
    delete entry.State;

    return stateBlock;
  }, []);

  return [cloneData, ...states];
}
```

The output is working as expected:

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Paul",
    "LastName": "Allen",
    "Entries": [
      {
        "EntryId": "FF-DD",
        "Title": "Item 1"
      },
      {
        "EntryId": "GG-RR",
        "Title": "Item 2"
      }
    ],
    "EmailAddress": "name@domain.com"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Lock 1",
    "CreatedTime": "1563479611",
    "EntryId": "FF-DD"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Lock 2",
    "CreatedTime": "1563479663",
    "EntryId": "FF-DD"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Run 1",
    "CreatedTime": "116479611",
    "EntryId": "GG-RR"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Run 2",
    "CreatedTime": "126347963",
    "EntryId": "GG-RR"
  }
]
```

Time as been renamed to CreatedTime and also include EntryId in each State. Delete all the States in the `Entries`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a little creative with [destructuring assignments with spread operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) and nested `.map()`s to accomplish this.

Details in code.

```js
const data = { FirstName: "Paul", LastName: "Allen", Email: "name@domain.com", Entries: [ { EntryId: "FF-DD", Title: "Item 1", State: [ { Name: "Lock 1", Time: "1563479611" }, { Name: "Lock 2", Time: "1563479663" } ] }, { EntryId: "GG-RR", Title: "Item 2", State: [ { Name: "Run 1", Time: "116479611" }, { Name: "Run 2", Time: "126347963" } ] } ] };

const newData = (() => {
  let states = [];
  //Loop through Entries
  let Entries = data.Entries.map(({State, ...others}) => {

    if (State) {
      //Map each state to new format
      let state = State.map(({Time, ...obj}) => ({...obj, CreatedTime: Time, EntryId: others.EntryId}));
      states.push(...state);
    }

    //Return Entitites without State
    return others;
  });

  //Remove LastName and Email from root object
  let {LastName, Email, ...dataWithoutName} = data;

  //Change Email to EmailAddress, combine all the pieces
  return [ {EmailAddress: Email, ...dataWithoutName, Entries}, ...states ]; 
})();

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: No. It need to match the same output like my code snippet. It also include a list of States outside of data object.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I've edited my answer. I'm adding some additional detail now.

Comment: Thank you. You forgot to rename Time to CreatedTime. Also is there a way to rename `Email` to `EmailAddress` and delete the `LastName` property?

Comment: Also EntryId missing in the State

Comment: Not for nothing, but rather than giving us a game of "Spot the difference", it'd be very helpful if you could clearly define all the changes you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: I have fixed my question to be more clear and expected response. Each State will have a `EntryId` and `Time` renamed to `CreatedTime`. In the data object rename Email to EmailAddress

Comment: I will do. Does it break if an Entry does not have `State` property?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I've added checking for `State` and also reduced the logic around `EntryId`. Originally I was checking to see if the object had `EntryId` because your object was mixed, though I see below you mentioned that was not intentional.

Answer (score -1):

Use `map` if you want to modify the contents of each item in a list in-place. Use `reduce` if you want to "boil-down" a list to one value.

```
function createArray(data) {
  let clone = { ...data };
  clone.Entries = clone.Entries.map(entry => {
      return Object.keys(entry).reduce((a, c) => {
        if(c === 'State') return a;
        a[c] = entry[c]
        return a;
      }, {})
   });
  return clone;
}
```

Running this on the given data will return

```
{  
  "FirstName":"Paul",
  "LastName":"Allen",
  "Email":"name@domain.com",
  "Entries":[  
    {  
      "EntryId":"FF-DD",
      "Title":"Item 1"
    },
    {  
      "Id":"GG-RR",
      "Title":"Item 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: Didn't realize you had two different keys, `Id` and `EntryId` in your Entries.

Comment: No, I still like to return the data object without State in the Entries

Comment: and I like to use spread, not hardcoded properties for mapping.

Comment: I have fixed the bug. It should be EntryId for all entry